Create time series in TimeScaleDB from filtered raw data
This is my first time using TimeScaleDB so I don't have a lot of experience with its usage patterns.
Here's the context: I'm building an analytics application that uses TimeScaleDB to generate time series of aggregated data computed from the data of projects in another application.
The basic flow is:

a periodic job calls the API of the main application to get the latest projects (since the most recent one fetched)
the analytics application has a database table where it saves the raw data of every project retrieved from the main application (this is in order to keep the full history available in case any projects are deleted on the main application, and to cache the data locally, preventing the analytics app from having to query for all the projects at once every time)
when the job is done fetching new projects, if a new project was fetched, it uses a function that takes all the projects, computes some aggregate statistics on those data (you can think of it as returning a JSON object with some fields in it, whose values depend on all the projects), and saves them with the current timestamp to a table named aggregated_statistics. This table has a TimeScaleDB hypertable, and it is the one used by the analytics application to expose via API the time series for the aggregated statistics.

I have the following requirement, which is subject to becoming more complex in the future: the project may belong to a group, and the consumer of the analytics API needs to be able to access the aggregated statistics filtering by group.
In order to implement this, here's what I thought:

the aggregated_statistics gets added a group_id, which is nullable
each time new tasks projects fetched, the aggregated statistics are computed using all the projects in the database; plus, for each group of the new projects, the statistics are re-computed only for the projects in those groups, adding an entry to aggregated_statistics for each group_id

This effectively yields a "global" time series, plus one time series per group.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work for more complex requirements, such as AND'ing or OR'ing the groups (e.g. filtering by two groups).
I can't think of anything else other than generating the time series on the fly with each request, which would be pretty taxing performance-wise. Is there a better way?

If you can calcualte statistics in SQL, you can create a continuous aggregate view in TimescaleDB that automatically keeps calculating statistics on the server side. Then you can just query these statistics from the view like you would query from any SQL table. In this case you would save the raw metrics to a hypertable and then the continuous aggregate view generates data out of this hypertable. Depending on what kind of metrics you are looking at this might be the path of the least pain.

Would saving the raw metrics in a hypertable work even though they are really not a time series? For a single project I only ever get one record: its data doesn't change over time, once I save it on the db it's over and done with

You need one key as the partition key for the hypertable. This is due to physical structure how TimescaleDB scales "big data". It is usually timestamp, but can be something else, as long as it is continuously increasing.

Also if you do not want to use TimescaleDB for some reason, you can create the same result with plain PostgreSQL aggregated views, though I am not the expert on the topic here. As far as I understand that what TimescaleDB has for "continuous" part is that that it continuously polls the hypertable and triggers view refresh.

I understand what you're saying, and I do want to use TimescaleDB. What I'm not sure about is I want to store the raw data in a hypertable. The raw data isn't the metric that we're interested in seeing change over time--that would be the aggregated statistics, which absolutely need TimescaleDB. I guess the problem lies in the fact that, rather than having to filter a time series (which would be pretty easy), I need to present in a time-series manner data that is computed as a function of filtered data. I can indeed probably compute at least some of the aggregations on the db

I don't know if you can run continuous aggregate views over other tables as hypertables.  As long as there is continuity in the data (more data gets added, the latest aggregated results change).


the raw data isn't the metric that we're interested in seeing change over time--that would be the aggregated statistics, which absolutely need TimescaleDB.

That's the perfect case for Timescaledb. You'll have:

The hypertable with raw data with the chunk time interval of like 1 day, with a retention policy of 1 day or week
A continuous aggregates in the minimal level with the aggregated statistics using a refresh policy every 1 minute.


As far as I understand that what TimescaleDB has for "continuous" part is that that it continuously polls the hypertable and triggers view refresh.

Timescaledb is not based on triggers to refresh or pooling mechanis. The continuous aggregates use a combined mechanism that tracks a watermark from what is missing to process and uses another temp table with "invalidation logs" to track updates in case some data in the past is updated.
Then, remember that continuous aggregates are also hypertables and you can enable compression, retention policies.

Let's say the raw data entry has a field called project_size. I am interested in having a time series that shows how the total project_size changes over time (i.e. the sum of the project_size of all projects in a certain time range). However, one entry simply contains the size of one project, and a created_at field which is when the project was created. The size of a project is static, so for a given project I only get one entry. How would you query say to get the total project size with a certain time bucket if the information in the db isn't the total size but the individual sizes?

In this case, just think about creating a narrow table like metrics (time timestamptz, metric_name text, value numeric) and then you can feed any metrics there  and rollup multiple aggregations over it. https://www.timescale.com/learn/designing-your-database-schema-wide-vs-narrow-postgres-tables

I don't think that answers it. I'll do a more practical example: let's say you want to track the total number of users of a site, but your analytics service only gets periodic notifications saying "at time x, y users signed up". How would you design your hypertable(s) in order to be able to answer the question "what's the total number of users in this time interval?" You cannot just do a time_bucket on the table that stores the "notifications", because then you'll get the total amount of users in that period. Whereas I need to be able to ask, how many users were there at x? And 1 hour later?
